# Replace Substring in a List of String

Tags: python, arrays, string, list, replace

I am trying to clean my sentences and what I want to remove these tags in my sentences (They are in the form of underscore followed by a word eg "_UH").
Basically I want to remove the string followed by an underscore (also removing the underscore itself)

text:

```
['hanks_NNS sir_VBP',
'Oh_UH thanks_NNS to_TO remember_VB']
```

Output Required:

```
['hanks sir',
'Oh thanks to remember']
```

Following is the code I tried:

```
for i in text:
    k= i.split(" ")
    print (k)
    for z in k:
        if "_" in z:
            j=z.replace("_",'')
            print (j)
```

Current Output:

```
ThanksNNS
sirVBP
OhUH
thanksNNS
toTO
rememberVB
RemindVB
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### With regex:

You can do it with [`re.sub()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub). Match the desired substring in a string and replace the substring with empty string:

```
import re

text = ['hanks_NNS sir_VBP', 'Oh_UH thanks_NNS to_TO remember_VB']
curated_text = [re.sub(r'_\S*', r'', a) for a in text]
print curated_text
```

Output:

```
['hanks sir', 'Oh thanks to remember']
```

Regex:

```
_\S* - Underscore followed by 0 or more non space characters
```

---

#### Without regex:

```
text = ['hanks_NNS sir_VBP', 'Oh_UH thanks_NNS to_TO remember_VB']
curated_text = [] # Outer container for holding strings in text.

for i in text:
    d = [] # Inner container for holding different parts of same string.
    for b in i.split():
        c = b.split('_')[0] # Discard second element after split
        d.append(c)         # Append first element to inner container.
    curated_text.append(' '.join(d)) # Join the elements of inner container.
    #Append the curated string to the outer container.
            
print curated_text
```

Output:

```
['hanks sir', 'Oh thanks to remember']
```

---

#### Problem with your code:

You are just replacing `'_'` with empty string when infact you want to replace `'_'` and characters after it with empty string.

```
for i in text:
    k= i.split(" ")
    print (k)
    for z in k:
        if "_" in z:
            j=z.replace("_",'') # <--- 'hanks_NNS' becomes 'hanksNNS'
            print (j)
```